# Get data from Cell of Gridview (without using label or textbox) and update to database in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, rows, itemtemplate

I am fetching data from database and populating in a Gridview. Now I have in update button. I want that when I click on that button, It will get data from each cell of Gridview and update it in th database. I am Facing problem in getting data from Cell of Gridview.

I have tied the following code, but it gives me empty string:

```
Protected Sub btn_update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_update.Click

For t As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Label1.Text += GridView1.Rows(t).Cells(1).Text.ToString()
    Next
End Sub
```

Where it is showing data in browser view (Image attached)

[image]
Following is my code for Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Roll_No">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("Roll_No")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="COLLEGE ROLL NO.">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <%#Eval("cRollNo")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="STUDENT">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("cName")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FATHER NAME">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("fName")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="REGN NO.">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("Reg_No")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MARKS">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" MaxLength="2" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Absent">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: So what is the problem/error? You are setting `Label1.Text` in a loop which seems to be pointless. Btw, why dont you use controls like `Label` if you use `TemplateFields`?

Comment: I am new to VB.Net, so please consider me as a learner.

1. When I click on Button, It is giving an empty string, but I want to return it the value of 2nd cell in each row.
2. I missed + before equal sign. Correct one is:

`Label1.Text += GridView1.Rows(t).Cells(1).Text.ToString()`

It will give value of all the cells in label.

If it is possible without TempleteFields?